# Symbols in Mac OS

Tags: macos

Where can I find those symbols on Mac OS such as Apple logo, small iPhone?

Answer (score 4):

You need the *Special Characters* Palette. You can usually access it from almost any program and it's a generic palette, so the changes you make, will be global and shared across applications.

It's almost always (by convention) located in the Edit menu of any application. In this case, this is Google Chrome's Edit menu:

[image: Edit]

Once you select the *Special Characters* palette, you will be presented with the following palette, where you have to click on it's "toolbar" 
and select Customize List:

[image: Special Char Palette]

From the sheet list, scroll down until you find Sign/Standard Symbols, and/or experiment with others. You can find things like: ☎☏✆��

Please bear in mind that:

1) The above screenshots were taken under OS X Lion (10.7), the Snow Leopard version of the Character palette is similar and you will find it in the same place, but as far as I can remember, won't allow customization, you'll have to play seek and find. :)

2) OS X Lion supports [Emoji](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji), which cannot be displayed in Stack Exchange and I'm not sure what other OSses support them natively. This is what the Emoji look like:

[image: Emoji]

Answer (score 2):

Open Keyboard from System Prefs & klick show Keyboard & Character Viewer in Menu bar[image]
Open language & text in SystemPrefs & select Input Sources, & check keyboard & Character Viewer.
[image]

Then go to the menu bar, click on the inout sources icon & choose character viewer.
[image]

Comment: Can't find them there.

Comment: Opps, my bad forgot a part will edit the answer

Comment: I mean I cannot find some specific symbols I am looking for in there.

Comment: Try to press Alt/Cmd/Ctrl/Shift in different combinations while Keyboard Viewer is opened and you'll see the magic :)

Comment: 'Shift' + 'Option' + 'K' =  Wohoo! :)

Comment: Some of the symbols you're looking for probably aren't in any of the default fonts -- there's no unicode character for "Apple logo" or "small iPhone". For those, you'll probably have to try to find and install a font like "Mac Dingbats" that contains Apple-related glyphs.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a Dashboard widget from [Tacowidgets](http://www.tacowidgets.com/widgets/) called **CharacterPal** that will display all of the extra characters in a small window. place your mouse over the character, and it will display the key combination to create the character.